# two threads querying a table

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I have a huge table about 1 m record , i want to do some processing on all records , so 1 thread way , would be , get say... 1000 record , process them , get another 1000 record etc...
but what if i want to use multitasking ? that is 2 threads each fetching 1000 record and do the processing in parallel , how can i make sure that each thread will fetch different 1000 record ?
note : am using hibernate

something looks like that

```
public void run() {


    partList=getKParts(10);
    operateOnList(partList);


}
```

Comment: You could put a function in your main thread that can be accessed by the 2 worker threads that will provide them with the range of data they should fetch. For exmaple the 1call would return 0..9, 2nd one 10..19, no matter who is calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import com.se.sas.persistance.utils.HibernateUtils;

public class FinderWorker implements Runnable {


    @Override
    public void run() {
        operateOnList(getNParts(IndexLocker.getAllowedListSize()));

    }

    public List<Parts> getNParts(int listSize) {

        try {

            criteria = .....
            // *********** SYNCHRONIZATION OCCURS HERE ********************//
            criteria.setFirstResult(IndexLocker.getAvailableIndex());
            criteria.setMaxResults(listSize);
            partList = criteria.list();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            session.close();
        }
        return partList;
    }

    public void operateOnList(List<Parts> partList) {
    ....
    }

}
```

locker class

```
public class IndexLocker {

    private static AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private final static int batchSize = 1000;

    public IndexLocker() {

    }

    public static int getAllowedListSize() {
        return batchSize;

    }

    public static synchronized void incrmntIndex(int hop) {
        index.getAndAdd(hop);
    }

    public static synchronized int getAvailableIndex() {

        int result = index.get();
        index.getAndAdd(batchSize);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can synchronize the code.

```
public class MyClass {

    private final HibernateFetcher hibernateFetcher = new HibernateFetcher();

    private class Worker implements Runnable {    
       public run() {    
         List partList = hibernateFetcher.fetchRecords();
         operateOnList(partList);    
       }
    }

    public void myBatchProcessor() {

      while(!hibernateFetcher.isFinished()) {
      // create *n* workers and go!

      }    
   }       
}

class HibernateFetcher {        

  private int count = 0; 
  private final Object lock = new Object();
  private volatile boolean isFinished = false;  
  public List fetchRecords() {

      Criteria criteria = ...;

      synchronized(lock) {
         criteria.setFirstResult(count) // offset
                 .setMaxResults(1000);
         count=count+1000;
      }
      List result = criteria.list();
      isFinished = result.length > 0 ? false: true;
      return result;
  }

  public synchronized boolean isFinished(){
    return isFinished;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please check the syntax, since I haven't tested this code. I don't have a hibernate project to test the code.

Comment: Hey Varun, Where are you processing the result (operateOnList) :)

Comment: i haven't worked with synchronized before , should i make it static ?

Comment: @Mak : as requested.. :)

Comment: count  should be volatile ? and or static to be shared for all threads right ?

Comment: yes, it can be managed with volatile too. But I personally avoid volatile. It's your call.

Comment: it's not working for some reason , i made each thread fetches only 1 record , when i print count in each thread , there overlapping 1
2
2
1

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you don't want 1m record fetched upfront but want it in batches of 1000 then to process them in 2 threads but make it parallel.
First you have to implement paging type feature in your database query using RowCount or something. From Java you can pass fromRowCount to toRowCount and fetch records in 1000 batches and process them parallel in threads. I am adding sample code here but you have to further implement your logic for different variables.

```
        int totalRecordCount = 100000;
        int batchSize =1000;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(totalRecordCount/batchSize);
        for(int x=0; x < totalRecordCount;){
            int toRowCount = x+batchSize;
            partList=getKParts(10,x,toRowCount);
            x= toRowCount + 1;
            executor.submit(new Runnable<>() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    operateOnList(partList);
                }
            });
        }
```

Hope this helps. Let me know in case further clarification required

Answer (score 0):

If your records in the database do have a primary key of type `int` or `long`, add a restriction to each thread to fetch only records from ranges:

```
Thread1: 0000 - 0999, 2000 - 2999, etc
Thread2: 1000 - 1999, 3000 - 3999, etc
```

This way you need only an `offset`, a `counter` and an `increment` for each thread. For example `Thread1` would have an offset of 0 while `Thread2` would have an offset of 1000. Because of two threads in this example, you have an increment of 2000. For each round increment the counter (starting at 0) of each thread and calculate the next ranges as:

form = offset + (count * 2000)
   to = from + 999

Comment: it's database sequenced

Comment: It does not matter. As long as the primary key can be ordered you may use this strategy. The one from @Varun Achar should work as well.